# In camera2, custom camera characteristics building is not working

Tags: android, android-camera2

I need to use custom camera characteristics, but it is not working when building. I saw camera2 official website's support custom characteristics.

I tried using sdk version 25, 26 and 28, but nothing is working.

```
CameraCharacteristics.Key<byte[]> key = new CameraCharacteristics.Key<>(name, byte[].class);
```

It shows error log when click rebuild project.

```
// error log display below:
<T>Key(String,Class<T>)在Key中不是公共的; 无法从外部程序包中对其进行访问
        CameraCharacteristics.Key<byte[]> key = new CameraCharacteristics.Key<>(name, byte[].class);
```

but I look over the origin code, `CameraCharacteristics.Key` is public.

Comment: Try to study new cameraX in jetback and use it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CameraCharacteristics.Key<?> cc = new CameraCharacteristics.Key<>(name, byte[].class);
```